# How to map two arrays to create objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays and I need to create objects like `{x: new Date(2019, 1, 1), y: 0}` The result of my arrays looks like this

`dates`

```
Array [
  "2019, 1, 31",
  "2019, 2, 28",
  "2019, 3, 31",
]
```

`monthlyTopUp`

```
Array [
  0,
  50,
  0,
]
```

Now each index from first array needs to match the index from second array.

What I've tried returned me an array with other arrays inside

```
Array [
  Array [
    "2019, 1, 31",
    0,
  ],
  Array [
    "2019, 2, 28",
    50,
  ],
  Array [
    "2019, 3, 31",
    0,
  ],
]
```

The way I've done this:

```
const array = [dates, monthlyTopUp];
const data = array.reduce(
  (dates, topUp) => topUp.map((v, i) => (dates[i] || []).concat(v)), []
);
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Seems like you have a solid groundwork, what have you tried?

Comment: i suggest array.map

Comment: @LiamMacDonald I am getting the last day of each month in a year then I calculate the total topUp transactions for each month. So now I need to make a graphic representation of this thats why I need to create objects in this format `{x: new Date(2019, 1, 1), y: 0}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array.prototype.reduce

```js
let arr1 = ["2019, 1, 31",  "2019, 2, 28",  "2019, 3, 31"];
let arr2 = [0, 50, 0];

let final=arr1.reduce((acc,value,i)=>{
let tempobj={};

tempobj["x"]=new Date(value.replace(/\s/g, "").replace(/,/g, "-"));
tempobj["y"]=arr2[i];
acc.push(tempobj)
return acc;


},[])

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do it like this:

```
var arr1 = ["2019, 1, 31",  "2019, 2, 28",  "2019, 3, 31"];
var arr2 = [0, 50, 0];

var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
    result.push({'x':arr1[i], 'y':arr2[i]});
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or array.map

```
var arr1 = ["2019, 1, 31",  "2019, 2, 28",  "2019, 3, 31"];
var arr2 = [0, 50, 0];

var result = arr1.map((v, k) => {return {x:v,y:arr2[k]}})

console.log(result);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fgo5wanh/

Comment: It would be better if you add a working fiddle too .

Comment: I added the fiddle now